# MSSQL Substring and keep the last word intact

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have the following example string:

> This string is very large, it has more then 160 characters. We can cut it with substring so it just has 160 characters but then it cuts of the last word that looks kind of stupid.

Now I want to have round about 160 characters, so I use `substring()`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('This string is very large, it has more then 160 characters. 
We can cut it with substring so it just has 160 characters but then it cuts 
of the last word that looks kind of stupid.', 0 , 160)
```

Wich results in:

> This string is very large, it has more then 160 characters. We can cut it with substring so it just has 160 characters but then it cuts of the last word that l

Now I need to find a way to finish off the last word, in this case the word `looks`

Any Idea whats the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Is the limit 160 chars? If so, you would want to remove the partial word from the resulting substring.

Comment: In this case the limit is 180. So I need to finish the last word ( `looks` in this example )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(500)= 'This string is very large, it has more then 160 characters. 
    We can cut it with substring so it just has 160 characters but then it cuts 
    of the last word that looks kind of stupid.'

SELECT CASE
         WHEN charindex(' ', @S, 160) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(@S, 0, charindex(' ', @S, 160))
         ELSE @S
       END
```

Comment: @S.Visser - Thanks! I doubted the `CASE` was necessary for a few moments hence fleeting deletion.

Answer (score 6):

If you go with 160, your last word is `that`.  If you go 165, your last word is `looks`.  Here's how you can do it with 160:

```
declare @string varchar(1000)
select @string = 'This string is very large, it has more then 160 characters. 
We can cut it with substring so it just has 160 characters but then it cuts 
of the last word that looks kind of stupid.'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, 1, charindex(' ',@string,160)-1)
```

Note:  This will error on strings less than 160 characters.  See Martin Smith's answer for handling that situation.

Comment: Should add a case statement so it doesn't fail if there's not a space at or after 160

Comment: Just one problem, when I have less then 160 characters it will give an error.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yeah, when I saw your answer, I realized that as well.

Comment: Replacing `charindex(...) - 1` with `ISNULL(NULLIF(charindex(...), 0) - 1, 999999)` will probably fix the issue of the string length's being less than 160 chars.